# Xcode server, bots, continuous integration, and unit-testing on the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ios-simulator, xcode-bots

I have an Xcode server set up with a few bots for iOS projects (compiled with Xcode 6.1), all of which containing unit test targets

I seem unable to have those tests run in the simulator; all tries so far have been failing with the same error (time-out for simulator to boot):

```
Test target NAME_OF_MY_TARGET encountered an error (Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at [...])
```

Of course, the log file path suggested is not a valid path on the server, thus making it impossible to check the logs

Comment: Hey! Did you ever find a solution for this? I have a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003556/xcode-7-0-1-bots-and-server-5-0-4-test-target-xx-encountered-an-error-tim

Comment: The path may be valid, but have invalid permissions. Using Terminal or Finder's [`Command`] +[`G`] to navigate will fail, but if you change the permissions on the root directory, you'll be ok.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue that was solved by changing the Xcode Bot to run only 1 of the latest version simulator (Xcode 6.3.1 and iOS 8.3) and force quitting all the simulator related processes on my server.

Just log onto your server and launch Activity Monitor, then go to the CPU tab, now search for "simulator", you should see a few results, just force quit all of them (even ones belonging to _xcsbuildd).  Here are examples of Process Names I have:

- com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
- iOS Simulator
- SimulatorBridge
- CoreSimulatorBridge

Comment: I ran into the same problem with Xcode7.1 and iOS9, and this was the only solution that worked out. By the way, in Xcode7 process “iOS Simulator” is now “Simulator”

Comment: Do you close your simulators this way before every integration?

Comment: This made my day a great one which was supposedly to end as a bad one. Double thumbs up!