# Xcode 7.0.1, Bots, and Server 5.0.4: Test target "xx" encountered an error - Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bots, xcode-server

**Expected Result:** You check the "Test" checkbox when creating a bot and Xcode server flawlessly executes mt tests like in the [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-415/).

[image]

**Result:** Xcode barfs up a bunch of simulator timeout errors and the integration fails.

[image]
`Test target "xxx" encountered an error (Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-0e5a387ef456a57b7a2d5a90d004256d/xxxx.log)`

**Environment:**

- Xcode 7.0.1
- Server 5.0.4
- OSX 10.11
- Replicated on two different machine with two different projects.
- Also, experienced this on OSX 10.10 and Xcode 6

**Real Problem:**
I'm a competent enough programmer with several years of iOS experience. It's hard to believe, although maybe it shouldn't be, that something that looks so simple in WWDC would fail so hard for on two different operating systems and versions of Xcode.

**Notes:**

- I'm running Xcode and Xcode Server from the same machine. I don't have to SSH in.
- The integration log file path that Xcode suggests checking is invalid, though I can get the raw build log from the Xcode

Here is a list of other people having similar issues, maybe it will help others:

- [Xcode server, bots, continuous integration, and unit-testing on the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507673/xcode-server-bots-continuous-integration-and-unit-testing-on-the-simulator) (Same issue, solution didn't work)
- https://github.com/czechboy0/Buildasaur/issues/84 (Not exactly the same, but related)
- http://joshuabrauer.com/2015/04/xcode-server-and-continuous-integration-ios (One of the few to have solved it, wasn't able to replicate)
- [Timeout when running xcodebuild tests under Xcode 6 via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380365/timeout-when-running-xcodebuild-tests-under-xcode-6-via-ssh) (Solution for Jenkins)
- [Xcode Server Simulator Times Out Waiting 120 Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004819/xcode-server-simulator-times-out-waiting-120-seconds) (unresolved)
- [Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035637/timed-out-waiting-120-seconds-for-simulator-to-boot) (Problem w/TeamCity CI - resolved in comments)
- https://devforums.apple.com/message/1040016#1040016 (Jenkins/SSH approach - solved*)
- http://www.openradar.me/22273042 (Radar)
- https://openradar.appspot.com/22413115 (Radar)
- http://www.openradar.appspot.com/18282084 (Radar)

Comment: I have found iOS sims to be very picky on CI situations. We recenlty moved away from TeamCity to XCode Server to OS X Server and stuff just works now (fingers crossed). I am however reseting the sims before every run of UI tests.

Comment: How do you reset the simulators? Can you describe? And more interesting, can you see the sims running on the buildserver?

Answer (score 2):

Please duplicate the radar https://openradar.appspot.com/23386199 so apple hopefully recognizes this strange behaviour

This worked for me: [Xcode server, bots, continuous integration, and unit-testing on the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507673/xcode-server-bots-continuous-integration-and-unit-testing-on-the-simulator?answertab=votes#tab-top)